# Handling or accessing file on in the RequestHandler uploaded in the POST request

Tags: api, postman, multipartform-data, tornado

Through POST request from postman i am sending multipart/ form-data with parameters along with file attachments. Now on the backend I am using tornado to handle these requests, I have no problem accessing params using `RequestHandler.get_argument("str")` (1st hyperlink for postman screenshot) however I am struggling to access/ read file attachment that is coming through the same request. As per tornado documentation I was using `RequestHandler.get_body_argument` and `.get_body_arguments` but both don't seem to work. Not sure if I am missing anything here in my backend. Can someone please help here?

```
Backend snippet:

dic = {}
dic['operation'] = RequestHandler.get_argument(self, name="operation"). << this is param in POST request from postman and I can get the value for key="operation" without any problem
```

[image: Accessing params within same request has no issue]

[image: Postman POST request with form-data having file]

But accessing file from form-data in backend using tornado as shown in above screenshot (2nd hyperlink to screenshot) has become struggle.

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded files are available under [`self.request.files`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.files).

```py
class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        for field_name, files in self.request.files.items():
            for info in files:
                filename = info['filename'] # name of the file

                content_type = info['content_type'] # content type of the file

                body = info['body'] # the data of the file

                # do something ...
```

Comment: Ahhhhh i did not realize that self.request.files is a dict. Okay this should work. Thanks a ton, let me try and update.

Comment: For some reason self.request.files is an empty dictionary. But i dumped the entire body im receiving using self.request.body.decode, it showed the filename as key and value as actual_file_name. Not sure if the content-type should not be 'application/json'. It is this content type in my case

Comment: @kittu You mean the content-type of the request is `application/json`? If so, you can't upload files like that. Either send the files as `base64` data, or use content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `enctype=multipart/form-data`.